Adapting Google Appointment website embed code to work with your own html button rather than the provided one
I have a client that is utilising Google appointment scheduling through their Google Workplace Calendar. Google have provided some sharing functionality that creates html code I can embed into their site however styling is minimal.
I would like to use their popup window scheduling tool but utilising my own html button which I can style pretty much how I want and to match the rest of the page.
This is Googles output code that they ask you to use:
<!-- Google Calendar Appointment Scheduling begin -->
<link href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/scheduling-button-script.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/scheduling-button-script.js" async></script>
<script>
(function() {
  var target = document.currentScript;
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    calendar.schedulingButton.load({
      url: 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/appointments/schedules/AcZssZ3NyjuNO6hzeazbQfHqzDb0iI1_MSX1qu4Nqq6y7NJmpUIqmE8NeI6mM6rW0GX_Qplfis6v4aIN?gv=true',
      color: '#039BE5',
      label: 'Book an appointment',
      target,
    });
  });
})();
</script>
<!-- end Google Calendar Appointment Scheduling -->

I can edit the button label, change colour but there is no option to further expand styloing here that I can see, for example I would like to add a border radius, increase font size, and increase font spacing.  Unfortunately any attempts to add to styling in the later half of the code simply breaks the script.
Can anyone see or have they already a solution whereby I can style the button, or use my own button and still get the pop-up effet creted by the script linking it to my clients G cal?

Google Appointment provides very limited options. Going through the code I found it is actually taking a target and appending the button adjacent to it. We can leverage that to style the button. Change 'YOUR_APPOINTMENT_LINK' to your link to test it.


<!-- Google Calendar Appointment Scheduling begin -->
<link href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/scheduling-button-script.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/scheduling-button-script.js" async></script>
<script>
(function() {
  var target = document.currentScript;
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    
    console.log('calendar', calendar);
    calendar.schedulingButton.load({
      url: 'YOUR_APPOINTMENT_LINK',
      color: '#039BE5',
      label: 'Book an appointment',
      target: document.getElementById('cal')
    });
    
    setTimeout(() => {

// Select the button adjacent to the div
const button = document.getElementById('cal').nextElementSibling;

      // Add inline styles to the button as the script adds inline styles only
      if (button) {
          button.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
          button.style.color = 'black';
          button.style.padding = '10px 20px';
          button.style.border = 'none';
          button.style.borderRadius = '5px';
      }
    });
  });
})();
</script>
<!-- end Google Calendar Appointment Scheduling -->

<p>First line</p>

<div id="cal"></div>

<p>Second line</p>

 



